# javascript split text

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, split, subtitle

hi i was wondering if someone could help me i want to split a block of text into sentences then split the sentence into words, i have managed to split the text sentence by sentence but i can not figure out how to split the sentences into words. i know if you replace "input.text.split('\r?\n')" the bracket values with space and it would split the text into word for word but i want it first to split the text sentence by sentence then word by word so that i can add custom styles. code is below , thanks in advance. p.s each sentence has a line break.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var parser = {
        outputString:  '',
        subtitle: function(input) {
          var words = input.text.split('\\r?\\n');
          var duration = input.end - input.start;
          var timeStep = duration/words.length;
          for (var i=0, l=words.length; i<l; ++i) {
            var time = Math.round((input.start + i*timeStep) * 1000);
            var text = words[i];
            var safeText = text.replace('"', '\\"');
            parser.outputString += '<span class="arabic" m="'+time+'" oval="'+safeText+'">'+text+'</span>';
          } //for
          return parser;
        }, //subtitle
    }; //parser

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
        var parsed = document.getElementById('parsed');
        parsed.style.width = window.innerWidth - 10 + "px";
        parsed.style.height = window.innerHeight - 10 + "px";
        parsed.value = '<div id="sura-body">' + parser.outputString + '</div>';
      }, false);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paneltext_da.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body>
     <textarea id="parsed"></textarea>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i still can not figure out how to add the html "`<p>`" to each sentence the data format am using is json. can some one help. thanks

```
            .subtitle({
          start: 6.057, 
          end: 9.07, 
          text: "Det er et af de vigtigste værktøjer i hverdagen.", 
          target: "subtitlediv"
        })   
        .subtitle({
          start: 9.07, 
          end: 15.02, 
          text: "Det er i browseren vi læser nyheder, ser TV, checker email, snakker med venner, shopper, booker billetter -", 
          target: "subtitlediv"
        })
        .subtitle({
          start: 15.02, 
          end: 18.08, 
          text: "Tusindvis af de ting vi efterhånden gør på nettet.", 
          target: "subtitlediv"
        })
        .subtitle({
          start: 18.081, 
          end: 23.021, 
          text: "Derfor er det også vigtigt hvilken browser vi bruger, og hvordan den virker.", 
          target: "subtitlediv"
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your function and i hope it will help you out. Check out the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rdz3s/

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `split(' ')`, assuming that your sentence uses space-delimited words to retrieve individual words.

Comment: hi, i know if i add space it would split the text for every space but i want to split it first for every like break and then by space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parser = {
    outputString: '',
    split: function(input) {
      var words = [];
      var sentences = input.text.split('\\r?\\n');
      sentences.forEach(function(sentence){
        words.push("<p class='sentence'>"); // tagged start of sentence
        words = words.concat(sentence.split(' '));
        words.push("</p>"); // tagged end of sentence
      });
      return words;
    },
    subtitle: function(input) {
      var words = this.split(input);
      var duration = input.end - input.start;
      var timeStep = duration/words.length;
      for (var i=0, l=words.length; i<l; ++i) {
        var text = words[i];
        if (text.search(/<\/?p/) === -1) {
          var time = Math.round((input.start + i*timeStep) * 1000);              
          var safeText = text.replace('"', '\\"');
          parser.outputString += '<span class="arabic" m="'+time+'" oval="'+safeText+'">'+text+'</span>';
        }
      } //for
      return parser;
    } //subtitle
  }; //parser
```

Comment: hi thanks for the code just wondering how would you implement that with the code that i have above.

Comment: hi, thanks for the code really much appreciate it, but just one question how can i add a "<p class="sentence"></p>" to the split sentences after it has split the sentence word for word. with the current code i have i can add the html class around the whole text but not for sentence by sentence.

Comment: hi, thanks nearly fixed the problem, the thing is it now it gives me the out put <span class="arabic" oval="<p class='sentence'>" m="14368"> then it gives me the html . code output <span class="arabic" oval="<p class='sentence'>" m="23860">
<p class="sentence">
<span class="arabic" oval="مَٰلِكِ" m="24967">مَٰلِكِ</span>

Comment: hi just wondering how do i remove the <span class="arabic" oval="<p class='sentence'>" m="23860"> from the js output.

Comment: @user5601 dunno if it's going to work for you. Regex control slows down the code. Both subtitle and split functions can be refactored.

Comment: hi, i tried the new code but it gives me a error on "if (text.search(/</?p/)" if i add brackets the js works but it does not remove the <span class="arabic" oval="<p class='sentence'>" m="23860">  html. any suggestions.

Comment: hi, thanks for the update but now it totally removes <p class='sentence'> . i just want the sentence that is split up in to word for word have a "<p>" around each sentence.  can you check my code above  i think it can be accomplished similar to that (there is a bug in my code), i am still learning js coding.

Comment: hi sorry to bother you i am still trying to figure out how to add the <p> code to the js